# "No such file or directory" when generating a gpg key

Tags: security, encryption, arch-linux, gpg

I'm trying to generate a gpg key

```
$ gpg --full-gen-key
```

but eventurally I get an error

```
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No such file or directory
Key generation failed: No such file or directory
```

I'm on Arch Linux.

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.15
libgcrypt 1.7.3
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /home/me123/.gnupg
.............
```

The directory /home/me123/.gnupg exists

Comment: Run `strace -o /tmp/foo gpg --full-gen-key` and then review the output.  Should then be clear what file or directory it's not finding.

Comment: If that doesn't solve it, you could also start `gpg-agent` with `strace`, just in case the error comes from there: `pkill gpg-agent; strace -o /tmp/gpg-agent.trace gpg-agent --daemon`.

Answer (score 63):

Did you delete the /home/me123/.gnupg directory and then it was recreated by gpg? If so, that's likely what is confusing the agent.

Either restart the agent (`gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`) or, more drastically, reboot your machine and try again.

Comment: Worked for me. See this for restarting the agent: https://superuser.com/questions/1075404/how-can-i-restart-gpg-agent

Comment: Worked like a charm in 2020 on Mac Catalina

Answer (score 19):

It would appear that the directory ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d (under some circumstances) is not being created or, is created with the wrong permissions.

```
# mkdir -p ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d
# chmod 700 ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d
```

Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add to this old thread, in case someone comes here looking for answers, that I had a similar issue on macOS (Big Sur 11.2). After deleting the `.gnupg` directory I had the same error as OP. The `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d` directory was recreated by GnuPG and had the correct permissions. Also, killing `gpg-agent` was not enough.

I noticed a strange file in the `.gnupg` directory named something like `.#k0x0000000130605a20.MBP-van-##REDACTED##.52431`. After I deleted that file, GnuPG worked like a charm again!

Comment: Solved for me. Thanks @justClouds.

Answer (score 2):

[Crossposting from a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647022/gpg-key-is-not-getting-generated-agent-genkey-in-gpg-is-looking-for-some-file/680853).]

In [this issue](https://github.com/MISP/MISP/issues/3702) this was called expected behaviour with the reason being a lack of ownership of the terminal-related device file. This can happen when e.g. starting the terminal as regular user, but running the `gpg` command as *root* via `su` or `sudo`.

Instead of doing wild stunts with `chmod` in the `/dev` tree, [this comment](https://github.com/MISP/MISP/issues/2372#issuecomment-452786029) demonstrates a quick fix using `tmux`. Basically just run the same `gpg` command within a `tmux` session, as `tmux` will take care of proper device file ownership.

Comment: What if I don't have tmux because my pacman is broken

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line to my `.zshrc` worked for me:

```bash
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have spent days trying everything I could think of, looking through forums, internet search results, etc., and this is the first thing that worked for me.