# GPG Key Gen Fails - no such file or directory

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

I believe I've read and tried all the suggestions, starting with [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/318385/52389) about the exact same issue.

I'm trying to generate a new key with:

`gpg --full-generate-key`

and it keeps ending with:

```
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No such file or directory
Key generation failed: No such file or directory
```

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-88-generic x86_64), headless

`gpg --version`

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4
libgcrypt 1.8.1
Home: /home/mark/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
    CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

I've killed gpg-agent and restarted the server multiple times.

`gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`

`ps aux | grep gpg-agent`

```
mark      1637  0.0  0.0  14428  1052 pts/0    S+   13:55   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn gpg-agent
```

The .gnupg directory permissions:

`drwx------   3 mark mark 4.0K Mar  6 14:01 .gnupg`

I've deleted ~/.gnupg multiple times, rebooting each time for good measure:

`ls -la ~/.gnupg`

```
total 12K
drwx------  3 mark mark 4.0K Mar  6 14:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 mark mark 4.0K Mar  6 14:01 ..
drwx------  2 mark mark 4.0K Mar  6 14:00 private-keys-v1.d
```

I've repeated the following several times with the same result:

[image: Trying to generate gpg key]

`ls -la ~/.gnupg`

```
total 16K
drwx------  3 mark mark 4.0K Mar  6 14:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 mark mark 4.0K Mar  6 14:04 ..
drwx------  2 mark mark 4.0K Mar  6 14:00 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-------  1 mark mark   32 Mar  6 14:01 pubring.kbx
```

I changed `pubring.kbx` to 700 and ran again, same result (grasping at straws)

`ps aux | grep gpg-agent`

```
 mark      1751  0.0  0.0  93316  3348 ?        SLs  14:02   0:00 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised
 mark      1758  0.0  0.0  14428  1084 pts/0    S+   14:06   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn gpg-agent
```

I also ran with `strace` but not sure how to decipher that output. Last line is `+++ exited with 2 +++`

```
strace -o /tmp/foo gpg --full-generate-key
```

I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Thanks for the link but it's the same one I linked to in the first line of this post.  That looked promising but my issue persists.  You can see above the screenshot, that directory exists with permissions 700 as described in that answer.

Comment: Mark sorry I totally missed that. Is SELinux maybe causing the issue?

Comment: @ValentinBajrami no, SELinux is not enabled - this is a box in a closet used for testing/learning.  I try to avoid any extra security measures to keep things simple and avoid possible confusion, like you mentioned.

Comment: Mark did you try it with another user?

Comment: @ValentinBajrami - I did not but after reading your question I did and it worked, with two different users.  So I tried it again using my account and it worked this time.  The only difference I can think of is that the machine had been powered down completely instead of just being rebooted.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Mark, good to hear and thanks for the feedback. This is a really strange edge case. Such an unfortunate that the classic "Did you try to turn it off and on again" did not work.

Answer (score 4):

```
gpg --gen-key --homedir /home/NEWUSER/.gnupg --passphrase "PASSWORD" --pinentry-mode loopback
```

Comment: Got the same issue on arch and this actually worked.

Comment: I don't understand why does this work. But gpg --full-generate-key doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into something that looked a lot like this...

In my case it was because I had `gpg-agent` running and had deleted the files it was referring to in order to "start again". By killing the old `gpg-agent` I resolved the issue.

Comment: Same here: `killall gpg-agent` does the trick :-).

Answer (score 1):

[Crossposting from a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647022/gpg-key-is-not-getting-generated-agent-genkey-in-gpg-is-looking-for-some-file/680853).]

In [this issue](https://github.com/MISP/MISP/issues/3702) this was called expected behaviour with the reason being a lack of ownership of the terminal-related device file. This can happen when e.g. starting the terminal as regular user, but running the `gpg` command as *root* via `su` or `sudo`.

Instead of doing wild stunts with `chmod` in the `/dev` tree, [this comment](https://github.com/MISP/MISP/issues/2372#issuecomment-452786029) demonstrates a quick fix using `tmux`. Basically just run the same `gpg` command within a `tmux` session, as `tmux` will take care of proper device file ownership.