# GPG key is not getting generated : agent_genkey in gpg is looking for some file

Tags: gpg, macos, gpg-agent

I'm facing issue to generate gpg key on my mac(`10.15.7 Catalina`). It is showing some error that the `agent_genkey` is looking for some file which is not available.
Below is the debug information from that :

```
% gpg --gen-key -vvvvv   
gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.1; Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

gpg: using character set 'utf-8'
gpg: Note: RFC4880bis features are enabled.
gpg: directory '/Users/test/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/Users/test/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
Note: Use "gpg --full-generate-key" for a full featured key generation dialog.

GnuPG needs to construct a user ID to identify your key.

Real name: test name
Email address: testname@gmail.com
You selected this USER-ID:
    "test name <testname@gmail.com>"

Change (N)ame, (E)mail, or (O)kay/(Q)uit? O
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
gpg: no running gpg-agent - starting '/usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.3.1/bin/gpg-agent'
gpg: waiting for the agent to come up ... (5s)
gpg: connection to the agent established
gpg: pinentry launched (12023 curses 1.1.1 /dev/ttys002 xterm-256color - ? 502/20 0)
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No such file or directory
Key generation failed: No such file or directory
```

gpg version is `2.3.1` and git version is  `2.30.0`.

```
% gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.1
libgcrypt 1.9.3
```

I have tried suggestions given in various post : like deleting the home directory (~/.gnupg), stopping the `gpg-agent`, reinstalling the `gpg` package (using brew).

It had worked around 1 month back. There was some issue with the previous keys . So, I had to delete those all and generate fresh and that is where the problem started.
Before reinstalling it, it was timing out in generation of gpg key . I had ran `dd` commands to help generate randomness. But that did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

In [this issue](https://github.com/MISP/MISP/issues/3702) this was called expected behaviour with the reason being a lack of ownership of the terminal-related device file. This can happen when e.g. starting the terminal as regular user, but running the `gpg` command as *root* via `su` or `sudo`.

Instead of doing wild stunts with `chmod` in the `/dev` tree, [this comment](https://github.com/MISP/MISP/issues/2372#issuecomment-452786029) demonstrates a quick fix using `tmux`. Basically just run the same `gpg` command within a `tmux` session, as `tmux` will take care of proper device file ownership.

Comment: I can verify that the TMUX trick in the comment works. Thanks! (although I still have no idea what the underlying issue is... )